# How to use jHiccup with Solr?

Tags: solr, garbage-collection, jvm, hiccup, azul-zing

I've tried use Solr with Jhiccup to analyze garbage collectors of Azul zing JVM and G1GC of Java-Hotspot. I launched solr, and want include jHiccup on it.  of solr process is 1078. I used following command: ./jHiccup -l /tmp/jHiccup-2.0.9/hiccup.%date.%pid -p 1078. It should be work, but an error is displayed : A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again. Help me please!

Comment: I'm afraid the set of developers who have experience in Solr + jHiccup + Zing and read Stack Overflow is empty :) Try submitting an issue [here](https://github.com/giltene/jHiccup/issues).

Answer (score 1):

re many ways for it to go wrong Using -p to attach to a running process is "touchy". It works well when the JDKs of both the target and the launching process are configured right, and match in version, but there are many ways for it to go wrong (mismatched JDK versions, varying policy setups, etc.).

In general the reliable and most common way to launch jHiccup (including within Solr) is to use the -javaagent method, as described in the README at https://github.com/giltene/jHiccup